# How to get the DCMTK library working in Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt-creator, dcmtk

I am trying to get DCMTK working in Qt Creator, but I got stuck at step 5. Please let me know if the other steps are wrong.

**Tools:**

Qt Creator: Qt Creator 3.5.1 (opensource), based on Qt 5.5.1 (MSVC 2013, 32 bit)

Visual Studio:
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013, version 12.0.40629.00 Update 5

DCMTK: v3.6.0

CMake: v3.3.2

**What I did:**

1. I generated the project files using CMake

[image]

2. I opened `C:\dcmtk-bin\DCMTK.sln` in Visual Studio and built `ALL_BUILD`

[image]

3. I restarted Visual Studio in admin mode, opened `C:\dcmtk-bin\DCMTK.sln` and built `INSTALL`

[image]

4. I started Qt Creator and created a new Qt Console Application
5. What do I need to add to the .pro file in order to get my project working?
   I have tried to add code from related questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355634/how-can-i-add-dcmtk-libraries-to-qtcreator-project) AND [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052148/how-to-use-dcmtk-in-qt) but I can't get rid of errors like

> Cannot open include file: 'dcmtk/config/osconfig.h': No such file or
>   directory

OR

> LNK1104: cannot open file 'dcmdata.lib'

My `main.cpp` file contains the following code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include "dcmtk/config/osconfig.h"
#include "dcmtk/dcmdata/dctk.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString mystr="Hellow world";
    qDebug() <<mystr;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: In the properties for the new Qt Console Application project, did you set the path in `C/C++ | General | Additional Include Directories`?  Similar thing for libs, `Linker | General | Additional Library Directories`.

Comment: Agree with Engo. To simplify it, you can find the libs yourself and copy them to a local folder. If not they should look something like this; LIBS +="D:/dcmtk-3.6.0/Lib files/Release" where the drive and path match your own dev system. The same goes for the include paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use DCMTK in Qt Creator you should add to your project *.pro file information about where DCMTK include files reside, where binaries reside and where linking file resides. So the simplest way is to create corresponding *.pri file and include it to your project file:

### DCMTK.pri (default build path for DCMTK library)

```
DCMTK_PATH = "C:/Program Files (x86)/DCMTK"

INCLUDEPATH += $${DCMTK_PATH}/include
LIBS += -L$${DCMTK_PATH}/bin \
        -L$${DCMTK_PATH}/lib

LIBS += -ldcmtk
```

### Myproject.pro

```
...

include(DCMTK.pri)
```